# GUI solution for converting PDF to TXT

Tags: 16.04, pdf

My ultimate requirement is to copy the text of a PDF file to the clipboard. If copying the text in the common viewers including LibreOffice, the text is not continuous but line by line. I wonder if there is a GUI solution for copying the text of a PDF file or perhaps convering the PDF to TXT or Word.

Comment: It might be better to ask this on [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Have you considered using OCR software?

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy thing to do by applying a PDF Converter. You can try [PDFMate PDF Converter Free](http://www.pdfmate.com/pdf-converter-free.html). It's a free program that enables you to convert your pdf to txt, doc, epub and other popular formats.

Comment: In an Ubuntu forum, you introduce a program, which is only available for Windows? Sure, Wine can help, but that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: To be honest, I don't like the Mac version, so I recommend the Windows one, which is much more powerful with all kinds of functions - converting, merging, password-protecting ...